# PHP fwrite with queue

Tags: php, queue, fwrite

I program the web application. I create the log. It is possible that more users will use the app in the same time. How to write the data into log in situation that more data in the same time will be send into log? For example two users will do something in the same time, so in the same time the program will send data in the log about it in the same time. How to manage it? Exists some buffer or queue? I'm afraid that the app will crash if I use only `fwrite()` function?

Comment: Use `file_put_content()` [follow this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) and set `FILE_APPEND` i.e. `file_put_contents("file_name", "file data", FILE_APPEND);`

Comment: Why should your application crash? Why don't you just try what happens?

Comment: @Jitendra And are you sure that the function doesn't crash if two users connect?

Comment: @Nico Haase How to try this? I'm not able to simulate this in one second.

Comment: This should be possible through [jMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) or [ab](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html)

Comment: @Kotryhel yes it will not crash if two user uses it same time